# Extrair apenas valor do teste de hipótese para um objeto

Tags: r

Boa noite

Estou realizando o teste de hipótese de KPSS para estacionaridade de séries temporais, através dos comandos a seguir.

```
#Todos os pacotes necessários para o desenvolvimento do curso
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(urca)
library(lmtest)
library(seasonal)
library(seasonalview)

x<-ur.kpss(AirPassengers)
print(x)
```

A base AirPassengers já é nativa do R

após a realização do teste não consigo extrair apenas o número do p-valeu do objeto x, o que me impossibilita de fazer em escala pra uma lista de muitas matrizes que tenho

Gostaria de ajuda para extrair o valor do p-valeu para outro objeto em forma de número, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O resultado do `ur.kpss` é um objeto de classe [S4](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s4.html). Para extrair elementos usamos o operador `@`:

```r
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(urca)
library(lmtest)
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

x<-ur.kpss(AirPassengers)
print(x)
#> 
#> ####################################### 
#> # KPSS Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
#> ####################################### 
#> 
#> The value of the test statistic is: 2.7395

x@teststat
#> [1] 2.739474
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>